# 301 redirect for "/usage" page while webalizer is installed

Tags: 301-redirect, vhost

I moved my site to another hoster and this hoster is using *webalizer*. My site has a page called `/usage`.

While testing I found out the page `https://example.com/usage/` generates the `403 Forbidden` error due to this `webalizer.conf`:

```
#
# This configuration file maps the webalizer log analysis
# results (generated daily) into the URL space.  By default
# these results are only accessible from the local host.
#
Alias /usage /var/www/usage

<Location /usage>
   # Alternative e.g. "Require ip 192.168.10"
   Require local
</Location>
```

OK, I renamed `usage` to `some-usage` and created a 301 redirect but apparently the configuration file has a higher priority.

**My question(s):**
Can I be more specific in `webalizer.conf` and tell Apache to ignore `/usage` **when** it is in the `https://example.com/usage/` context, or, how can I set the 301 redirection so it works.

**Edit:** Is it a possible solution to change the `Alias` line to this:

```
Alias /webalizer-usage /var/www/usage
       ^^^^^^^^^^ is added.
```

I don't know which impacts this change would have.

I personally would prefer the solution where Apache ignores `/usage` in the `https://example.com/usage` context.

Comment: "I renamed `usage` to `some-usage`" - in both the `Alias` and `Location` directives? _And_ restarted Apache? "and created a 301 redirect" - where did you redirect from/to? (What is the redirect supposed to do?)

Comment: The redirect should redirect `usage` to `some-usage` but apparently the `vhost` file has a higher priority.
However, I would prefer to rename `usage` to `webalizer-usage` as I added it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I personally would prefer the solution where Apache ignores `/usage`

I think I'm missing something, but if you have access to the server config then *removing* the `webalizer.conf` file entirely from your config would seem to resolve your problem? (Providing you don't need URL access to the Webalizer stats?)

Alternatively, change the URL used in the `webalizer.conf` file, as you suggest:

```
Alias /webalizer-usage /var/www/usage

<Location /webalizer-usage>
   # Alternative e.g. "Require ip 192.168.10"
   Require local
</Location>
```

(Presumably `/var/www/usage` is a location outside of your document root?)

As with any change to the server config, you will need to restart Apache for the change to take effect.

> and created a 301 redirect but apparently the configuration file has a higher priority

Well, not necessarily. It depends how you are implementing the redirect and where. It is perfectly possible to implement a redirect in `.htaccess` that overrides an `Alias` defined in the server config. (eg. A simple mod_alias `Redirect` looks at the requested URL, so will always override an `Alias`. However, a mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` matches against the URL-path *after* the request has been mapped to the filesystem, so it won't match the *source* of an `Alias` - *unless* the `RewriteRule` is used directly in the server config or vhost context, in which case it matches against the URL-path *before* the requested has been mapped to the filesystem. But even then, you could base the redirect on the `REQUEST_URI` server variable, which contains the URI, not the filesystem mapping.)

I assume the purpose of the redirect is to...

1. Change the URL in your application from `/usage` to `/some-usage`
2. **Redirect** `/usage` to `/some-usage` in order to preserve SEO, if `/usage` was already indexed / linked to (overriding the `Alias`). ... this isn't necessarily an essential part of the puzzle, unless SEO is a concern.

Since #2 overrides the `Alias` anyway, it is far more preferable to change the Webalizer URL, as mentioned in the first part of my answer.

Comment: An alternative to deleting the webalizer.conf would be disabling it using `sudo a2disconf webalizer` on a Debian based system.   An alternative to restarting Apache is to have it reload its configuration like `sudo service apache2 reload`.

Comment: Yes, I changed the Alias and I am happy with the solution. Thx.